# How to pull data from Account to Activity?

Tags: formula, account, activities

I created a Text Field on Account.

I want to create a field on Activity so that my Account Field displays there.

Is that possible? if so, How?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom field in Setup > Object Manager > Activities > Fields & Relationships (in Classic, Setup > Customize > Activities > Fields). From there, use the formula type, a return type appropriate for your field, and the formula would use the field relationship path (e.g. `Account.Name` or `Account.Some_Custom_Field__c`).

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you Fox! Have a great day! Tytytyty

Comment: @Steve You're welcome!

Comment: curiously, the formula editor for Activities doesn't allow you to point-and-click via the `Account` relationship; instead, you have to type in manually as noted in the answer.